# npm run webdriver-manager-update seems bugged

Tags: selenium, npm, protractor, webdriver-manager

It's my first practical expirience in using of npm package manager so don't beat me : ). Running npm at windows 8 I faced with a error which could not fix.

That's what I got: [npm error](http://tinypic.com/r/2yjpufr/8)

As you can see, script throwed an error when faced with "**.**" symbol. Think it's because windows does not support partial links like "./bla/blabla/blablabla".
Also by some reason the path to webdriver-manager seems to be broken. It starts with 'C:\' and ends with './node' because the symbol '>' (dunno how to name it) separates them in two lines. Still do not understand how to fix it on windows 8. Suppose that webdriver-manager script thinks that './node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager'  is the absolute path to this script.

Comment: Have you searched into the [related GitHub issues](https://github.com/angular/protractor/search?q=webdriver-manager+update&ref=cmdform&type=Issues)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with npm on windows but the linux command is simply `webdriver-manager update` with space and without "npm run".

Comment: Have you installed Java Development Kit (JDK)? [required by Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/808)

Comment: even made chown on the selenium folder = )

Comment: You may have to specify chrome binary path in your protractor config. What's the error message? [docs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Comment: I even put the path to my 'chromedriver' binary. If I manually run the chromedriver from console then it works fine. If I try to run the tests from npm, it fails

Comment: heh, I tried to run the tests when selenium was turned off...) When I ran selenium  through webdriver-manager, tests were passed.

Comment: So, problem solved? :)

Comment: it does not matter already... Anyway, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an old issue that hasn't been resolved. Hopefully this will help.

The error you are seeing comes from the "webdriver-manager-update" script in your package.json file. I imagine that your scripts tag looks something like:

```
"scripts" {
    "webdriver-manager-update": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
}
```

This would work on linux and mac but it will not work on a Windows machine. Packages that register an executable binary in their package.json (with the "bin" keyword) will register a symlink / shortcut in their "node_modules/.bin" folder. Node knows about this path so you just need to change your script to:

```
"scripts" {
    "webdriver-manager-update": "webdriver-manager update"
}
```

Then you can run it with: `npm run webdriver-manager-update`

If you need to launch this command from the file path without having a command registered in the "scripts" portion of your package.json, then you'll do something like:

```
node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```